# Kotlin JS JSON deserialization

Tags: javascript, json, kotlin

I use kotlin on javascript platform. This code fails on the sixth line with exception "Uncaught TypeError: a.c.iterator is not a function".

```
class A(val b: String, val c: List<String>)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a = JSON.parse<A>("""{"b": "b_value", "c": ["c_value_1", "c_value_2"]}""")
    println(a.b)
    for (c in a.c) println(c)
}
```

In javascript debuger I can see, that object "a" is deserialized. But I think, it is not a valid kotlin object of type A. Is any way, how to create valid kotlin object instance of type A from the object "a" or from original json string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not use `JSON.parse` with regular Kotlin classes. Use it with external interfaces instead, i.e.:

```
external interface A(val b: String, val c: Array<String>)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a = JSON.parse<A>("""{"b": "b_value", "c": ["c_value_1", "c_value_2"]}""")
    println(a.b)
    for (c in a.c) println(c)
}
```

Sorry, such restriction can't be expressed via Kotlin type system.

And yes, as @marstran mentioned, you should not use `List<T>` and other Kotlin collections in this case. We are working on a library for deserializing JSON to Kotlin JS classes (similar to Jackson in JVM), but I can't say anything about the timeframe yet.

**UPD**: there's [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) library which maps Kotlin classes to and from JSON.

Comment: I use same classes on the server (jvm) part of the application. So I can't use external interface. I used class A(val b: String, val c: Array<String>), which is also working. Array instead of list is important.

Comment: Sorry, but currently it's a limitation of Kotlin JS. You'll have to duplicate your server-side DTO classes with external interfaces.

Comment: This post saved me. Even though, I hope the Kotlin-classes will be supported soon...

Comment: @guenhter They *are* supported now. See update to my initial answer.

Comment: @AlexeyAndreev cool. Is there something to consider, because yesterday, I tried to deserialize a Json (`{ "a" : [ 1, 2, 3 ] }` and it didn't worked out too well. The deserialisation itself worked, but when looping over the list, an error appeared; something about *no iterator ...*

Answer (score 0):

Now for this case (map JSON to Kotlin class), you can use preview of [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization)

Check [Dynamic object parser](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/runtime_usage.md#dynamic-object-parser-js-only) section for an example of parsing json to real Kotlin data class, not to external interface